# What is the purpose of AgentRestart.dat

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest

can some tell me what is the purpose of the file AgentRestart.dat?
I see it in the current folder of my unit test session (e.g. ...\TestResults\mycomputer_DE-L070221 2012-02-29 17_59_49\Out). Usually in that folder I find the assembly with the unit tests and all the other referenced assemblies. But in this partical case no file is located in the folder except AgentResult.dat.

Further I can report that the unit tests run as desired and when debugging Environment.CurrentDirectory shows that particular folder.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

When I added a DeploymentItem using the Test Settings menu, I got the same result you did.

To get things working, I had to do the following:

- Remove the DeploymentItem from the Test Settings menu
- Use a DeploymentItemAttribute in my code instead
- Restart Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (did not work prior to restart)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a test category to a test case that is failing

   [TestCategory("RestrictToJustOneTest")]
2. run MSTest.exe with error tracing such as

(Win key + R ) "powershell"
cd /d C:\TestResultsDirectory
    & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"  /testcontainer:"your.ddl /category:"RestrictToJustOneTest" /detail:duration /detail:errorstacktrace >> C:\test.log

or "cmd" 
cd /d C:\TestResultsDirectory
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"  /testcontainer:"your.ddl /category:"RestrictToJustOneTest" /detail:duration /detail:errorstacktrace >> C:\test.log